# AWS S3 upload timeout (HTTP API)

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload large (5MB) file to AWS S3.

My request

```
POST https://my-bucket-name.amazonaws.com/

Form Data
...
```

In devtools this request become (canceled) after exactly 120 sec. This looks like timeout on AWS side? Can I increase it somehow?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-retry-timeout-sdk/Accroding to this article there is definitely timeout issue. But there is no option for HTTP API (((

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-retry-timeout-sdk/ correct link

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should POST to `https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/` instead of `https://my-bucket-name.amazonaws.com/`. `s3` is missing.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect request example. My URL actually is `my-bucket-name.s3.dualstack.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/` and it's correct. Upload success with small files and good internet connection. But on 3G and 5MB files I have timeout error.